# HP Elite Thunderbolt 3 Dock with HP Elite x2 1012

Tags: hp, thunderbolt

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 but it seems that there is still no support for the Thunderbolt Dock. The dock would provide RJ45-Network connection, displayport, audio output, USB-A connections, and VGA, but nothing of that is working with Ubuntu and I don't like to use the Windows which came with the x2. Is there any solution or anything I can do to support a solution for this configuration?

Comment: did you disable the dock security in BIOS?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint, that was the problem, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by disabling the dock security in BIOS (see comments).

Comment: This answer is proven working with following configuration:  HP Elite Thunderbolt 3 Dock connects to a `HP ZBook 17 G3/80D6, BIOS N81 Ver. 01.44 10/31/2019` running `Ubuntu 16.0`